# how to add css to buttons based on index in angular 2?

Tags: angular

In my angular 2 app I have buttons

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let item of array;let i = index" (click)="nextpage(i)">{{i+1}}</button>
</div>
```

When I click one button it has to get style and reaming won't get styled. Is there any option `let index` will start with 1

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let item of array;let i = index" (click)="nextpage(i)" [style.background-color]="getStyle(i)">{{i+1}}</button>
```

and the getStyle function:

```
getStyle(i){
    if(i==1){
        return "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: button is styleling bro Thanks.can i add more styles like [style.background-color,style.font,etc] to getstyle()(Method)

Comment: yes you can also add css class with `[NgClass]` :) accept answer if it works fine

Comment: ya,i clicked on it helpful but my reputation is less than 15 bro